# Writing macros which generate statements

Tags: scala, scala-macros

With intention of reducing the boilerplate for the end-user when deriving instances of a certain typeclass (let's take `Showable` for example), I aim to write a macro, which will autogenerate the instance names. E.g.:

```
// calling this:
Showable.derive[Int]
Showable.derive[String]
// should expand to this:
// implicit val derivedShowableInstance0 = new Showable[Int] { ... }
// implicit val derivedShowableInstance1 = new Showable[String] { ... }
```

I tried to approach the problem the following way, but the compiler complained that the expression should return a `< no type >` instead of `Unit`:

```
object Showable {

  def derive[a] = macro Macros.derive[a]

  object Macros {
    private var instanceNameIndex = 0

    def derive[ a : c.WeakTypeTag ]( c : Context ) = {

      import c.universe._
      import Flag._

      val newInstanceDeclaration = ...

      c.Expr[Unit](
        ValDef(
          Modifiers(IMPLICIT), 
          newTermName("derivedShowableInstance" + nameIndex), 
          TypeTree(), 
          newInstanceDeclaration
        )
      )

    }
  }
}
```

I get that a `val` declaration is not exactly an expression and hence `Unit` might not be appropriate, but then how to make it right?
Is this at all possible? If not then why, will it ever be, and are there any workarounds?

Comment: I don't think it's possible (though I'm not sure). As a workaround you could create a macro annotation that adds implicits to an object and than just import fields from that object like this: `@implicits(Showable.derive[Int], Showable.derive[String]) object MyImplicits; import MyImplicits._`.

Comment: I'd be very interested in seeing the error message. My currently operational devices can't run Scala, so I can't check it out by myself. Would appreciate if you could post compilation results here.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako The error is `type mismatch; found   : <notype> required: Unit...`

Comment: Could you post the reproduction as a github project? Looks like a genuine bug.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako Sure. https://github.com/sorm/sorm/tree/notype-scala-issue. Just run `mvn compile` on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's right. Declarations/definitions aren't expressions, so they need to be wrapped into Unit-returning blocks to become ones. Typically Scala does this automatically, but in this particular case you need to do it yourself.

However if you wrap a definition in a block, then it becomes invisible from the outside. That's the limitation of the current macro system that strictly follows the metaphor of "macro application is very much similar to a typed function call". Function calls don't bring new members into scope, so neither do def macros - both for technical and philosophical reasons. As shown in the example #3 of my recent "What Are Macros Good For?" talk, by using structural types def macros can work around this limitation, but this doesn't look particularly related to your question, so I'll omit the details.

On the other hand, there are some ideas how to overcome this limitation with new macro flavors. Macro annotations show that it's technically feasible for the macro engine to hook into new member creation, but we'd like to get more experience with macro annotations before bringing them into trunk. Some details about this can be found in my "Philosophy of Scala Macros" presentation. This can be useful in your situation, but I still won't go into details, because I think there's a much better solution for this particular case (feel free to ask for elaboration in comments, though!).

What I'd like to recommend you is to use materialization as described in http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/implicits.html. With materializing macros you can automatically generate type class instances for the user without having the user write any code at all. Would that fit your use case?

Comment: Yeah, I've read about materialization, and unfortunately it doesn't fit my case, nor does it feel very typesafe. The problem is that I use typeclasses to control which types are supported by cerain methods, so I need a facility for the end-user to specify the supported types deliberately. So, summarizing your words, I shouldn't expect a support for this to appear in 2.11 and even 2.12?

Comment: Definitely not in 2.11, because it's practically code frozen. 2.12 is very far away, so everything's possible. And macro annotations... You can already use them in 2.10 with macro paradise.